# Not all my data is loading when i use Paging in a DataGrid ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

First here's my code.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="AllCadView" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DataGrid ID="DGAllCadDrawings" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="datag"
            HorizontalAlign="center" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="1" OnDeleteCommand="RunDelete"
            OnEditCommand="RunAllDeptsEdit" Font-Size="Larger" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="100"
            OnPageIndexChanged="AllCadViewsListGrid_PageIndexChanged" AllowCustomPaging="true">

            <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#EEDC82"
                HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="#666666" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
            </PagerStyle>
            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#FFFACD" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <FooterStyle Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#FFFACD" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#FFFACD" />
            <ItemStyle BorderColor="#666666" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="white" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateColumn Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="AllDeptsbtnEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Internal/DGedit.png"
                            CommandName="Edit" CausesValidation="false" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Internal/DGdelete.png"
                            CommandName="Delete" CausesValidation="false" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="UID" HeaderText="Drawing ID"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DrawNumName" HeaderText="Drawing Name/ Pattern Number" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
                </asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Descript" HeaderText="Description"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="File Path">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdLink" runat="server" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilePath") %>'
                            OnClick="linkAllButtonClick" Text='<%# Eval("FilePath") %>' ForeColor="#B13E0F"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

<%--                    --%>

```
public DataSet LoadNextPageDataGrid()
{
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spEN_LoadAllDeptsCad", sc2);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    if (DrawIDSearchTextBox.Text != "")
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrawID", DrawIDSearchTextBox.Text);
    }

    if (DrawNumNameTextBox.Text != "")
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrawNumName", DrawNumNameTextBox.Text);
    }

    if (DescriptionTextBox.Text != "")
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", DescriptionTextBox.Text);
    }

    if (FilePathTextBox.Text != "")
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", FilePathTextBox.Text);
    }
    if (DeptsDDL.SelectedIndex != 1 && DeptsDDL.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", DeptsDDL.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
    sc2.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);
    sc2.Close();

    return dt;

}

protected void AllCadViewsListGrid_PageIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Change current page index and reload datagrid.
    DGAllCadDrawings.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    DGAllCadDrawings.DataSource = LoadNextPageDataGrid();
    //LoadDataGridAll();
    DGAllCadDrawings.DataBind();

}
```

Now if I turn off the paging all my data loads just fine, but with paging it only loads the first 100 and there is no 2nd page link. I'm loading in around 9k rows of data. Hopefully that's clear enough for you guys to understand my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set allocustompaging = false. or remove it However you are loading all 9000 rows in a single datagrid. better try sql paging in stored procedure

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Pagination-in-ASP.Net-Gridview-Control.aspx